# login before processing POST data asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, post

I am working on web form ... HTML form that posts data to aspx page , but before the server process post data .. the user should be logged in ... so it has to redirect user to login page if not logged in .  the problem is post data will be lost when redirecting ,the data is huge to be in session (up to 20 mb)

the data are files in base64 form (strings)

so how I keep post data while user login redirection ??

Comment: Please specify the nature of the 20MB post data i.e. files or images or XML or text?

Comment: it`s base64 format .. any type of files

Comment: Can you just make sure they are logged in before they access the form that posts the data? Or, does it have to all be in one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should require them to log in before they fill out the form.

If you can't do that, you can save all that data in a database table and/or physical folder for temporary information.

After they log in, you can transfer the data from the temporary location to where you want it.